# Hibernate criteria with restrictions on children

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a Hibernate criteria call that I want to execute in one SQL statement.  What I'm trying to do is select instances of Parent that have Children with a property in a range of values (SQL IN clause), all while loading the children using an outer join.  Here's what I have so far:

```
 Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);

 c.createAlias("children", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
          .setFetchMode("c", FetchMode.JOIN)
          .add(Restrictions.in("c.property", properties));

 c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

 return c.list();
```

Here's some sample data:

```
Parent
Parent ID
A
B
C

Children
Child ID    Parent ID   property
...         A           0
...         A           2
...         A           7
...         B           1
...         C           1
...         C           2
...         C           3
```

What I want to do is return the parents and ALL their children if one of the children has a property equal to my bind parameter(s).  Let's assume properties is an array containing {2}. In this case, the call will return parents A and C but their child collections will contain only element 2. I.e. Parent[Children]:

A[2] & C[2]

What I want is:

A[0, 2, 7] & C[1, 2 3]

If this is not a bug, it seems to be a broken semantic.  I don't see how calling A.getChildren() or C.getChildren() and returning 1 record would ever be considered correct -- this is not a projection.  I.e. if I augment the query to use the default select fetch, it returns the proper children collections, albiet with a multitude of queries:

```
  c.createAlias("children", "c").add(
      Restrictions.in("c.property", properties));
```

Is this a bug? If not, how can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 6):

```java
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);

c.createAlias("children", "children");
c.add(Restrictions.in("children.property", properties));

c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

return c.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

getChildren() is just the name of the getter/setter, your query will determine how the objects get populated.

I'm going to guess here that the first part spits out

```
SELECT * FROM Parent 
INNER JOIN Child c ON ... 
WHERE c.property in (x,y,z)
```

which doesn't get you what you want. What'd you'd want to do if you were writing this in raw SQL is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Parent  
WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT DISTINCT parentID FROM Child WHERE  c.property in (x,y,z))
```

rearranging your criteria appropriately might do the trick if the last one isn't producing this query.  (Could you also post what hibernate is generating for each?)

Comment: Right, the SQL is the easy part.  What I'm looking for is the criteria calls. ;)  Also, keep in mind this will require an outer join to populate the child entities.

Comment: So is the 2nd query getting the parent and the lazily loading the children?

Comment: Yes, for each parent record returned a child query is being executed which is what I'm trying to avoid.  It looks like this may actually be a defect, but I'm curious if anyone has a workaround: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3524

Answer (score 0):

I would start the Criteria with the child class. You'll get a list with all the children, and then you can iterate and get the parent for each children.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in work around way.

```
Criteria c1 = session.createCriteria(Child.class);
c1.add(Restrictions.in("property", properties));
c1.setProjection( Projections.distinct( Projections.property( "parentId" ) ) );
List<Integer> parentIds = c1.list();

Criteria c2 = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
c2.createAlias("children", "children");
c2.add(Restrictions.in("id", parentIds));
return c2.list();
```